# How do I design a primary key for time-series data in DynamoDB?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a data model that consists of 8 entity types and I need to design a DynamoDB NoSQL model around some access patterns. The access patterns are not entity specific so I am in the process of translating them, but most of the access patterns rely on getting items by a date range. From previous related questions, people usually assume that getting the item by both an itemID (Partition Key) and date range (Sort Key) is the norm, but in my case, I need to get all entities by a date range.

This would mean the partition key is the entity type and the sort key is the date range. Am I correct with this statement?

Given the large size of the data (>100GB), I am not sure if this is true.

### Update: List of access patterns and data example

The access patterns so far look like this:

```
Get all transactions during a given date range
Get all transactions during a given date range for a given locationId
Get all transactions during a given date range for a given departmentId
Get all transactions during a given date range for a given categoryId
Get all transactions during a given date range for a given productId
Get all transactions during a given date range for a given transactionItemId
Get all transactions during a given date range for a given supplierId
Get all product on transactions during a given date range
```

And a transaction entity has the following attributes (I have only included a snippet but there are 52 attributes altogether):

```
identifier  
confirmationNumber **(contains date information)**
priceCurrency   
discount    
discountInvoiced    
price   
shippingAmount  
subtotal    
subtotalInclTax 
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please add example data and a list of access patterns, to me the description sounds ambiguous.

Comment: I've updated the post with your recommendations

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DynamoDB will make you very happy for this use case, you seem to have a bunch of different filter categories, that's typically not what DynamoDB excels at.

An implementation would require lots of data duplication through global secondary indexes as well as trouble with hot partitions. The general approach could be to have a base table with the PK as the date and the timestamp as the SK. You then create global secondary indexes based on locationId, departmentId and the other categories you filter by. This will result in data duplication and depending on your filter categories hot partitions.

I'd probably use a relational database with indexes on the filter fields and partition that by the transaction time.

Comment: I know this increases expense and essentially duplicates the data. Are there no application examples where DynamoDB can handle such filters efficiently? [This particular example with adaptive capacity](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/) is what led me to believe hot partitions could be handled in the background.